# Using Python in Apache Flink to do analytics

Tags: python, apache-flink, pyflink

Is there any way to do analytics on flink jobs using Python specifically? The table api as far as I understand will retrieve the data and we can only use the functions in the api to transform the data. Did i miss or misunderstand anything in the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

You can define custom Python UDF or Pandas UDF to transform your data which you can refer to https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.11/dev/table/python/python_udfs.html#user-defined-functions and https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.11/dev/table/python/vectorized_python_udfs.html